# Spring'16 Communities Login Page Issue: Link to launch SelfRegister Page routes to the wrong URL

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, login, napili, spring16

When the Spring'16 Communities Template Update was released, we switched to standard login page provided by the template. Previously, we used pages from Site.com Studio and had a Custom Lightning component for Self Registration.

Now after we switched, the link that points to Self Registration page is  routing to the wrong Link. Somehow /community is appended to the URL.
[image] 
**Community Builder Edit Page:**

[image]

**Community Self Register Page Properties:**

[image]

We have been facing this issue for a while now and I tried almost everything I know and still could not figure out the issue. Finally, reverted back to the old Login page we used before the upgrade.

So, While trying to understand the cause of this issue, I found a few things by using tools such as Chrome Dev tools etc.,

So, here is what I know so far:

1. Clicking the link triggers an onclick event handler.
2. Then the community Self Registration URL is retrieved from the server and stored in a Aura component Attribute on the Login Component. (**v.communitySelfRegisterUrl**)
3. Then this attribute is returned which is opened in a new tab.

Server Side Controller: **LoginFormController**.
Method which returns the URL: **getSelfRegistrationUrl**.

[image]

Also please look at the following controller I found

[Javascript Controller for Login Page](http://pastebin.com/cLurEVfZ)

Now, I have no idea what to do next. Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Fixed this by using a Custom Component instead. Tried reaching out to Salesforce Support and communities. Nothing Helped.

> Note: This works on Napili Template Summer'16 Version as of now. Dont
>   know if this can be applied to other templates.

1. Create a Custom Lightning component with the links to "Forgot Password" and "Self Registration" Links.
2. Hide the Standard Link Section using CSS- Set the display style attribute to none. (Custom CSS in branding Editor).
3. Then add the custom component in the space of hidden account.

Hope this helps.